# How can I remove multiple consecutive characters within a word with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I want a regular expression (in Python) that given a sentence like:

```
heyy how are youuuuu, it's so cool here, cooool.
```

converts it to:

```
heyy how are youu, it's so cool here, cool.
```

which means maximum of 1 time a character can be repeated and if it's more than that it should be removed.

```
heyy ==> heyy
youuuu ==> youu
cooool ==> cool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use back reference in the pattern to match repeated characters and then replace it with two instances of the matched character, here `(.)\1+` will match a pattern that contains the same character two or more times, replace it with only two instances by `\1\1`:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r"\1\1", s)
# "heyy how are youu, it's so cool here, cool."
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new empty text and only add to it if there aren't 3 consecutive

```
text = "heyy how are youuuuu, it's so cool here, cooool."

new_text = ''
for i in range(len(text)):
    try:
        if text[i]==text[i+1]==text[i+2]:
            pass
        else:
            new_text+=text[i]
    except:
        new_text+=text[i]

print new_text
>>>heyy how are youu, it's so cool here, cool.
```

eta: hmmm just noticed you requested "regular expressions" so approved answer is better; though this works